# vim keep cursor position when counting matches

Tags: function, vim

I have a function to count and return the number of matches of some text:

```
function! count_matches()
    redir => matches_cnt
    silent! %s/\[\d*\]//gn
    redir END
    return split(matches_cnt)[0]
endfunction
```

I created a map to insert the return value of count_matches() at the current position:

```
noremap <C-A> Go[foo<C-R>=count_matches()<CR>]
```

However the cursor jumps to the beginning of the line after executing the silent %s/[\d*]//gn command. So when I press control+a vim inserts "[foo", then the function is being executed, the search command resets the cursor position and the return value is inserted at the beginning of the line resulting in "1][foo" instead of "[foo1]".

Can I somehow prevent count from changing the cursor position, or reset the cursor position after counting the matches?

The script also leads to an error, if the pattern is not found. How can I get the function to return 1 without an error for zero matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even better then just to save the cursor position, is to save the complete viewport. (But that only works, if you do not change the window layout)

See `:help winsaveview()`

```
let wsv = winsaveview()
MoveTheCursorAround
call winrestview(wsv)
```

In your particular case, I would take another approach:

```
inoremap <expr> <f3>  len(split(join(getline(1,'$'),"\n"), '\[\d\+\]',1))
```

Which takes the whole text, and splits it on the pattern `\[\d\+\]` and then counts how many elements there are. Or if you like to add some text:

```
inoremap <expr> <f3>  '['.len(split(join(getline(1,'$'),"\n"), '\[\d\+\]',1)).']'
```

This will add the `[` in front and `]` after the number. Adjust the mapping key and text to your personal taste. (Note, you do not need the `winsaveview()` function, cause the cursor won't move).

It is perhaps not such a good idea to use that function on a multi MB text size. ;)

Comment: Thanks! Also: do you happen to know how I can prevent the function to output an error message for zero matches and return 1 instead?

Comment: It works, if I switch "<expr>" and "<f3>" and close the last bracket, but how can I use the return value in a different key mapping?

Comment: I do not understand the question

Comment: sorry, and thanks again for the help! I want to have a key map: imap control+a some_text [number_of_matches]<'Esc>msGo[number_of_matches]:some_more_text<'Esc>`s

Comment: Okay, see my adjustment.

Comment: Could the downvoters please explain, why they downvoted? I see no problem here.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same function, reworked to return `1` when there's no match:

```
function! count_matches()
    redir => matches_cnt
    try
        silent! %s/\[\d*\]//gn
    catch
        echo 1
    endtry
    redir END
    return split(matches_cnt)[0]
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

See `:help getpos()`

```
let save_cursor = getpos(".")
MoveTheCursorAround
call setpos('.', save_cursor)
```

Comment: Also see `:h winsaveview()`

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
function! CountWithCursorKeep(...)
    let currentCursor = getcurpos()
    let pattern = expand('<cword>')
    if a:0 > 0 | let pattern = a:1 | endif
    execute(':%s#' . pattern . '##gn')
    call setpos('.', currentCursor)
endfunction

nmap ,ns :call CountWithCursorKeep(<C-R>/)<cr>
nmap ,nw :call CountWithCursorKeep(expand('<cword>'))<cr>
nmap ,nW :call CountWithCursorKeep(expand('<cWORD>'))<cr>

command! -nargs=? -bar -complete=tag CountMatch call CountWithCursorKeep(<f-args>)
```

You can use `:CountMatch pattern` to get how many times pattern occurs in current file.